# Compressing image to exact fileSize

Tags: c#, image, resize

I am working on application which should compress Jpeg to exact size (128kB). I have tried saving it with quality level but I dont really get how this thing works. When I put there 100L quality, it will give me even bigger file that was before. Also I have problem with more iterations. When I want to change quality of picture for the second time, it will give me GDI+ error...

Edit: I need picture smaller than 128Kb, It doesnt have to be exactly that value

Comment: Of course 100% will increase the file size, what else did you expect? To approach a certain size you will need to try various quality levels, always using the original, of course and always writing to temporary file(s). To explain the GDI error we need to see the code, although we can guess that you try to overwrite the file while it is still loaded.. You can never be sure to really hit the given size exactly.

Comment: To tell the truth I expected that 100% will give me 100% of the size, not 150%...

Comment: You need to learn about `jpg`, its __artifacts__ and the problems that arise when you try to __'preserve'__ them..